# ampersand in email address (href)

Tags: html, html-entities, ampersand

Im working with email address which has an ampersand in it,
the user wants a 'contact us' link to open up a new message wit their address populated,
I normally use href, but the ampersand is causing this not to work,
any idea's?

here's what i have at the moment:

```
<a href="mailto:L&D@gha.org.uk? subject=MessageTitle&amp;" 
        style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: large; font-weight: bold; color: #800000">#GHA Organisation Development</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of plain `&`. Your href URL is inside HTML so it needs to be escaped properly to be valid HTML.

Comment: +style your CSS in external stylesheets instead of using inline declarations

Comment: is that a direct swap then, &amp; for &?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: This answer is technically incorrect. It doesn’t need to be escaped to be valid (although it’s probably a good idea to do so, to avoid confusion). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584172/ampersand-in-email-address-href/8890899#8890899).

Comment: @Mathias This answer was written without HTML5 definitions in mind, just HTML4 (where, according to the specs you link, it needs to be escaped). That said, even though this may be strictly valid HTML5, it still *does* cause problems in practice.

Comment: @KonradRudolph “This answer was written without HTML5 definitions in mind, just HTML4.” Well, why? “[E]ven though this may be strictly valid HTML5, it still does cause problems in practice.” Only in case the ampersand is ambiguous (which is invalid as per the spec). There are no cross-browser issues otherwise; HTML5 is backwards-compatible and specs current behavior.

Comment: @Mathias: No, the OP said that *her case* causes problems, even though it’s unambiguous according to HTML5. As to why the answer was written without HTML5 in mind: because, at the time (early 2010, almost two years ago!), HTML5 wasn’t relevant yet.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Which problems? All browsers interpret `<a href="mailto:L&D@gha.org.uk?subject=MessageTitle&amp;">test</a>` the same way. The only ‘problem’ I can think of is that it doesn’t validate according to outdated HTML versions (or if you use a broken validator). “HTML5 wasn’t relevant in early 2010.” …

Comment: @Mathias Since the OP didn’t say, I don’t know which problem it causes. Perhaps the OP uses an XHTML doctype? … I’d rather not guess when “escape the ampersand” is such a simple and fool-proof guideline.

Comment: @Konrad What difference does using an XHTML DOCTYPE make? There’s only a difference if you serve the document as `application/xhtml+xml` (but if you do that, you have bigger problems…).

Comment: @Mathias That was implied (obviously, since otherwise the doctype will just be ignored by the browser).

Comment: @KonradRudolph It wouldn’t be ignored by the browser; it still triggers standards mode.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is **not** an *ambiguous ampersand*, so it’s perfectly valid to use the HTML you suggested. The currently accepted answer is incorrect (even though I agree it’s a good idea to always encode ampersands to avoid confusion).

The HTML spec defines ambiguous ampersands as follows:

> An ambiguous ampersand is a U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&) that is followed by one or more characters in the range U+0030 DIGIT ZERO (0) to U+0039 DIGIT NINE (9), U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A to U+007A LATIN SMALL LETTER Z, and U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to U+005A LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z, followed by a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;), where these characters do not match any of the names given in the named character references section.

Entities that don’t end in a semicolon (like `&amp`) are handled differently in attribute values, though:

> If the character reference is being consumed as part of an attribute, and the last character matched is not a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;), and the next character is either a U+003D EQUALS SIGN character (=) or in the range U+0030 DIGIT ZERO (0) to U+0039 DIGIT NINE (9), U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to U+005A LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z, or U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A to U+007A LATIN SMALL LETTER Z, then, for historical reasons, all the characters that were matched after the U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&) must be unconsumed, and nothing is returned.

But this doesn’t apply here since the next character is `@`.

FWIW, I’ve researched this thorougly and wrote about my findings here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands

I’ve also created [an online tool](http://mothereff.in/ampersands) that you can use to check your markup for ambiguous ampersands or character references that don’t end with a semicolon, both of which are invalid. (No HTML validator currently does this correctly.)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyGPK.png]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. &amp is automatically added when I sent the confirmation email link through the mail. It causes an error because I had sent mail in Plaintext format that is why &amp was automatically added.
so, in that situation, I sent a send an email in HTML format. Then problem solved.

In my code I just added 'mail.IsBodyHtml = true'. for sending email in html format.

Comment: Question is related to ampersand in mail address and not in body.